# ReferenceError: io is not defined - socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, io, electron

I'm trying to connect my socket.io server from the Electron app but I get this error:

[image: Error from electron side]

How can I fix this problem? I've tried every single types of connecting but i cant get io() so I can't connect the server.

Index.html:

[image: My index.html content is here]

Script to connect to server:

[image: this is my script that connecting the server]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include code and errors as text.

Comment: Possible issue with the src attribute path.  Where is this payload.js in relation to index.html?    Is it complaining about the ```const socket = io()```?

Comment: it is in same directory with index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem here!

I added payload.js manually in index.js, not in with `webPreferences` attribute in main.js and I set the type as module like this: `<script type="module" src="payload.js"></script>`

and now my electron app is connecting the server perfectly!